# How to add css to cmsplugin_filer_image in Django CMS?

Tags: html, css, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I'm a little bit confused, I can't understand how to add a custom style for images which are placed in text using cmsplugin_filer_image?
I've followed instructions from here: https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer#customisation

Stucked at the moment where I have to add css to boxed.html. I'm using `<<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/cmsplugin_filer_image/css/boxed.css">` and can't understand for now where to place classes from `boxed.css`

Here is the `boxed.html` code (I've copied it from default.html and placed in my app dir e.g. `project_y/src/templates`:

```
{% load thumbnail filer_tags filer_image_tags %}{% spaceless %}
{% comment %}
    You may change the image size for special cases in your project by overriding
    this template. There are a few size manipulation filters for this in
    `filer_image_tags`:

    {% if placeholder == 'my_special_sidebar' %}
        {% thumbnail instance.image opts.size|extra_padding_y:10 crop=opts.crop upscale=opts.upscale as thumbnail %}
    {% else %}
        {% thumbnail instance.image opts.size crop=opts.crop upscale=opts.upscale as thumbnail %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if instance.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{% endif %}<img{% if instance.alignment %} class="{{ instance.alignment }}"{% endif %} alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ thumbnail.url }}"{% if instance.caption %} title="{{ instance.caption }}"{% endif %} />{% if link %}</a>{% endif %}
{% endcomment %}

{% if link %}<a href="{{ link }}"{% if instance.target_blank %} target="_blank"{% endif %} class="filer_image_link">{% endif %}
{% if instance.image %}
    {% if instance.use_original_image %}
        <img class="filer_image {% if instance.alignment %}{{ instance.alignment }}{% endif %}" alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ instance.image.url }}"{% if instance.width %} width="{{ instance.width }}"{% endif %}{% if instance.height %} height="{{ instance.height }}"{% endif %}{% if instance.caption %} title="{{ instance.caption }}"{% endif %} />
    {% else %}
        {% thumbnail instance.image size crop=opts.crop upscale=opts.upscale subject_location=opts.subject_location as thumbnail %}
        <img class="filer_image {% if instance.alignment %}{{ instance.alignment }}{% endif %}" alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ thumbnail.url }}"{% if instance.width %} width="{{ instance.width }}"{% endif %}{% if instance.height %} height="{{ instance.height }}"{% endif %}{% if instance.caption %} title="{{ instance.caption }}"{% endif %} />
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {# just a plain link to some external image #}
    <img class="filer_image {% if instance.alignment %}{{ instance.alignment }}{% endif %}" alt="{% if instance.alt %}{{ instance.alt }}{% endif %}" src="{{ instance.image_url }}"{% if size.0 %} width="{{ size.0 }}"{% endif %}{% if size.1 %} height="{{ size.1 }}"{% endif %}{% if instance.caption %} title="{{ instance.caption }}"{% endif %} />
{% endif %}
{% if instance.caption or instance.description %}
    <span class="filer_image_info">
        {% if instance.caption %}<span class="title">{{ instance.caption }}</span>{% endif %}
        {% if instance.description %}<span class="desc">{{ instance.description }}</span>{% endif %}
    </span>
{% endif %}
{% if link %}</a>{% endif %}

{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: I understand that my classes should be placed somewhere in `<img class="....` but i can't understand what to write there. I've tried to place `leftalign` (in css it got properties `float` and `margin`), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've decided to add `float:left` to all images in the web-page. It could be done in `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css` for `img` class.